# How to use automapper with grpc repeated types

Tags: c#, automapper, grpc, proto

I have the following  google proto models

```
message PlatformsDTO
{
    repeated .cms.PlatformDTO Platforms = 1;
}
message PlatformDTO{
    string Code = 1;
    string Name = 2;
    bool IsActive =3;
}
```

and below class implementation of my platforms model

```
public class PLATFORMS
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

what I would like to achieve is to map PlatformsDto's repeated Platforms property into `List<PLATFORMS>`

I would appreciate any help as I don't have any clue on how to do this..

Answer (score 0):

You can config **Automapper** like this:

```
CreateMap<PLATFORMS,PlatformDTO>().ReverseMap();
```

and then in your **service**:

```
//todo: get result **data** from gRPC

var result = _mapper.Map<List<PLATFORMS>>(data);
```